# CW-Structure of Spin(n)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I cannot find any information about the CW-Structure of $Spin(n)$ groups. Clearly $\pi_1=\pi_2=0$ and I think $H_3(Spin(n))=\mathbb Z$ $(n\geq 5)$, so the $3$-skeleton is $S^3$. What is the $4$-skeleton?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each $n$ there is a fibration sequence

$$Spin_n\rightarrow Spin_{n+1}\rightarrow S^n$$ covering the corresponding fibration sequence $SO_n\rightarrow SO_{n+1}\rightarrow S^n$. The point is that the inclusion $Spin_n\hookrightarrow Spin_{n+1}$ is $(n-1)$-connected, so the $4$-skeleton of $Spin_n$ is the same as the $4$-skeleton of $Spin_6$ for each $n\geq 6$.

Now $Spin_5\cong Sp_2$ and it is know that $Sp_2\simeq S^3\cup_{\nu'} e^7\cup e^{10}$, so the $4$-skeleton of $Spin_5$. Of course $Spin_3\cong S^3$ and $Spin_4\cong S^3\times S^3$ which have $4$-skeletons $S^3$, $S^3\vee S^3$ and $S^3$, respectively.

Also $Spin_6\cong SU_4$ and the $5$-skeleton of $SU_4$ is $\Sigma \mathbb{C}P^2\simeq S^3\cup_{\eta_3}e^5$, so by the previous comments, in fact the $5$-skeleton of $Spin_n$ for $n\geq 6$ is $S^3\cup_{\eta_3}e^5$.

We also have a fibration $G_2\rightarrow Spin_7\rightarrow S^7$, and it's not that difficult to see that $Spin_7\simeq S^3\cup_{\eta_3}\cup e^6\cup e^6\cup\dots$, which gives the $6$-sekelton of $Spin_n$ for $n\geq 7$. In fact, the previous fibration splits when localised away from $2$ so there is a $\frac{1}{2}$-local homotopy equivalance $Spin_7\simeq G_2\times S^7$. Finally we mention that there is a homeomorphism $Spin_8\cong Spin_7\times S^7$, so you get the $7$-skeleton of $Spin_8$ from that of $Spin_7$ wedged with an extra $7$-cell. I'm not aware of any further isomorphisms for the higher rank spinor groups.

A full CW decomposition was given by Araki in his paper *On the homology of spinor  groups*, which was predated by some related results of Borel in *Sur I'homologie et la cohomologie des groupes de Lie compacts connexes*. As you might expect, the results tend to get a bit complicated as the rank grows, and whilst Araki calculates explicit attaching maps, he does not explicitly calculate their homotopy classes, so depending on what information you are looking for, you may be more interested in his homological calculations. And to this end I should refer you to the paper *The integral homology and cohomology rings of $SO(n)$ and $Spin(n)$* of Pittie, which does exactly what it says.

Comment: Real dumb question:  why is the $4$-skeleton given using cells up to 5 dimensions?  Also, how does one see that the $4$-skelton is $\Sigma \mathbb{C}P^2$?  (I have heard that $Sq^2:H^3(SU(n);\mathbb{Z}_2)\rightarrow H^5(SU(n);\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is an isomorphism (for large enough $n$) but never new a proof.  Computing the $4$-skeleton would give me a proof!)

Comment: I think that that was a typo and the $4$-skeleton of $Spin(n)$ for $n\geq 6$ is just $S^3$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito, yeah, that was just a typo, that's really the 5-skeleton, which is where the next cell lives, so it kinda seemed relevant to include that information. Thanks for the correction, Wilhelm.

Comment: @JasonDeVito, There is a map $\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^3\rightarrow SU_4$ given by sending a complex line to the generalised reflection through it (modulo a bit of fiddling to sort out the $\det=1$ condition). This map is exactly how the CW structure of $SU_4$ is defined by Yokota and Whitehead, and I can try to dig out some similar references to the above if you are interested. Basically, if you follow Hatcher's discussion of the cohomology of $SO_n$, the same ideas go through to the complex case.

Comment: @Tyrone:  (and Wilhelm).  Thanks.  I do very little pure homotopy theory, so figured I was just messing up something little.  And no reason to dig up any references - I am ok with blackboxing certain results.  I will mess around a bit with your suggested map $\Sigma \mathbb{C}P^3\rightarrow SU(4)$ and see what I can prove.  (And, should the same argument work for $\Sigma \mathbb{C}P^2\rightarrow SU(3)$?)

Comment: @JasonDeVito, you may consider working first with $U_n$ and using the homeomorphism $U_n\cong S^1\times SU_n$. Now define $A:S^1\times S^{2n-1}\rightarrow U_n$ by $A(\lambda,x)z=(\lambda-1)<x,z>x+z$ and note that it factors over $\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}_+$. A bit of simple redefinition gives you the map $\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}\rightarrow SU_n$. Check that $A$ restricted to $\mathbb{C}P^{n-2}$ takes values in $U_{n-1}$. Now you have a projection map $p:U_n\rightarrow S^{2n-1}$ as well as a map $q:\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}\rightarrow S^{2n-1}$ pinching to the top cell. Compare $p\circ A$ and $q$.

Comment: I will try this out soon - before I delve to deep, what does the subscrip $+$ indicate in the notation $\Sigma \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}_+$?

Comment: It's a disjoint basepoint. Defined as I have written it, the map factors over $S^1\times\mathbb{C}P^1/\ast\times\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$, which is exactly $\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}_+$.

Comment: (Feel free to ignore me!)  The disjoint basepoint is confusing me because the relevant quotient space is obviously (path) connected.  I have now gotten as far as proving that $A$ really does land in $U(n)$ and that $A$ factors to $S^1\times \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}/\{1\}\times \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$, which is $\Sigma \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ with the two cone points identified.  I'll continue to work on it.  Thanks for putting up with me!

Comment: @JasonDeVito, the basepoint is taken before the suspension is performed. The notation is standard, if a little sloppy. Think of it as $\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}_+=S^1\wedge(\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}_+)=(S^1\times \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}\sqcup S^1\times +)/(S^1\times +\sqcup \ast\times \mathbb{C}P^{n-1})=S^1\times\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}/\ast\times\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the basepoint you can define $B:S^1\times S^{2n-1}\rightarrow U_n$ by $B(\lambda,x)=A(\lambda, x)\circ A(\lambda^{-1},[e_1])$ and study this new map instead. It makes some of the matrix formulas a bit more complicated if I recall, but may make the homotopy theory easier to line up.

Comment: With regards to the disjoint basepoint: I should have realized that $\Sigma X_+$ means $\Sigma(X_+)$ as opposed to $(\Sigma X)_+$ exactly due to my concern above!  When I have time later today, I'll continue to fight with this problem.  Thanks again!